# Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid, Google Auth error

Tags: firebase, react-native, web, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Hello i am trying to connect firebase to my react native app and trying to implement google authentication i am stuck for many days and don't know anything about this error
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch.

I have connected my project to Firebase that connection is proper
I have added android app in firebase to my web app too

I tried everything. Doing this for 7 days still cannot fix this

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
  webClientId: 'Not adding here',
  androidClientId: 'Not adding here',
  // androidClientId:"xd",
});
useEffect(() => {
  if (response?.type === 'success') {
    const { id_token, access_token } = response.params;
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token, access_token);
    signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  `your text`;
}, [response]);
```

Comment: The key to your problem is the error message `redirect_uri_mismatch`. That error means that the `Redirect URI` that your app is using does not match what you configured for the OAuth Client. Search Q&A on Stack Overflow for `redirect_uri_mismatch`.

Comment: do you use expo go ?